addOnSuccessListener on firebaseMessaging.token does not get called on a Samsung device
I am trying to get the token from firebaseMessaging once login is successful, this is my code
   package com.google.firebase.messaging;

   override suspend fun updatePushMessageToken() {
        firebaseMessaging.token.addOnSuccessListener {
            Timber.d("test firebaseMessaging.token")
            externalScope.launch {
                updatePushMessageToken(it)
            }
        }
    }

The above code does not on some Samsung phone example -  Samsung A52
the timber logs don't get printed.
Gradle has:
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging")

has any one faced similar issue with this code please?
any pointers on what might be the issue
thanks
R

the Task returned from the token provides more than just a success callback, did you see if any other callbacks get called like the failure or canceled ones?

Can you please edit your question and add the error message that you get when you attach a failure listener?
